# Javascript: take text from the webpage, change it, and display the web page again

Tags: javascript, html

I am quite new to the javascript. I am planning to do a web page which changes text from other webpages to something funny. It is like google translate page. The page itself looks the same, only all text changed to something else.
So, in my page, user will enter url of the page he want to change text and then my script must parse it, change some words and display it again.
So, problem is following:

- What javascript libraries would be good to parse the html documents.
- I will change it, but how can I display the changed web page again?
  Is there any useful function?

Comment: What other frameworks are you using? You're displaying a webpage inside of your page?  A few more details might be helpful. As of right now, it doesn't look like you need any special javacript library to do this. just target the item you want to change and change text. $(document).ready(function() { $('#targetItemID').value('Lorem ipsum dolor amet consequat.'); });

Comment: I am not using anyting yet, I am in the stage when I am looking for the tools to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [UFrame](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26330/UFrame-goodness-of-UpdatePanel-and-IFRAME-combined) if you you are still looking for a solution.

**The Reason**
 - UFrame combines the goodness of UpdatePanel and IFRAME in a cross browser and cross platform solution. It allows a DIV to behave like an IFRAME loading content from any page either static or dynamic. It can load pages having both inline and external JavaScript and CSS, just like an IFRAME. But unlike IFRAME, it loads the content within the main document and you can put any number of UFrames on your page without slowing down the browser. It supports ASP.NET postback nicely and you can have DataGrid or any other complex ASP.NET control within a UFrame. UFrame works perfectly with ASP.NET MVC making it a replacement for UpdatePanel. Best of all, UFrame is implemented 100% in JavaScript making it a cross platform solution. As a result, you can use UFrame on ASP.NET, PHP, JSP or any other platform.

Here's and [Example](http://labs.omaralzabir.com/UFrame2005/)

**About the example** - Notice that each Uframe is essentially like a mini browser in your webpage. This means you can then adjust text with basic javascript, or for that matter virtually any way you'd like.

You would target and change an piece of text like this:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('#IDofElementToChangeHere').value('This is new text will now be displayed!');
});
```

Hope that helps. :)

Answer (score 1):

Little sense, TRUE, but sense none the less...

this has been a big issue for me recently when trying to retrieve an xml file from an ebay site or API if ye wanna be specific.

thing is there is a few ways which i'll list below but few ever work properly and no one seems to give a straight answer!

---

### XMLHttpRequest()

```
url='http://someURL.com';
xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET',url,false);
xhr.send();
response=xhr.responseText;
```

---

### Script Element

```
<script src="someURL"></script>
```

But you then need to retrieve the data, which I'm still workin on...

---

### iFrame Element

```
<iframe src="someURL"></iframe>
```

Haven't tried this yet but holds same problem with retrieving the markup.

---

### aJax.get()

```
req=$.ajax({
    type        : 'GET',
    url         : 'someURL',
    dataType    : 'jsonp',
    jsonp       : 'callbackname',
    success:
        function(response,status,request){},
    error:
        function(request,status,error){},
    complete:
        function(request,status){}
})
```

All Have their limitations but the **script tag** seems to have limitless potential, assuming you can retrieve the data from the element!